# gettext setup not working

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, locale, gettext

I had gettext working, but now it suddenly won't translate. I get find out whats going on. I am trying to use `/sys/locale/no_NO/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po` to translate the page to norwegian.

/public/home.php

```
$locale = "en_US";
if (isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) $locale = $_COOKIE['lang'];
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("messages", "../sys/locale");
textdomain("messages");

echo "<p>locale: " . $locale . " "; 
echo gettext("Home"); 
exit();
```

This prints out

`locale: no_No Home` when I should be `locale: no_No Hjem`

Comment: Try to add `putenv("LANG=$locale");`. That's the last level environment variable gettext probes, but sometimes helps. Otherwise `LANGUAGE=` which has higher priority than `LC_ALL=` and allows for alternatives `no_No:nl_NL:en_GB`

Answer (score 1):

I see you are fighting with norwegian. I had the problem with Debian servers too which just support nb_NO and nn_NO but not no_NO. 
The solution is to use the exact names of locale names as folder and setting:

Make sure you have the locales installed:

```
$ locale -a
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
nb_NO.utf8
nn_NO.utf8
```

So the php setting for norwegian bokmål:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nb_NO.utf8');
putenv('LANGUAGE=nb_NO.utf8');
```

The path to the PO files should have the same name e.g.:

```
./i18n/nb_NO.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
```

I guess the same solution will work for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

With Japanese I have to do the following:

```
putenv("LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8");
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'ja_JP.UTF-8');
bindtextdomain('messages', '../locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('messages');
```

With other languages I find I do not always have to add the encoding suffix, it is very inconsistent.  Similarly I cannot just use "ja" when "en" works fine.

`setlocale` returns false unless the locale is listed in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` but translations will often work despite the error.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reconfigure locales:

Install debconf (I.e. Run apt-get update then apt-get install debconf, as root)

Run dpkg-reconfigure locales as root

This code worked for me:

```
//Put this in cookie for example

$lang = GetPrefLanguage($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);

$language = $lang . '.utf8';

setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

// Set language
putenv('LANG='.$language);

// Specify location of translation tables
bindtextdomain('traductions', dirname(__FILE__).'/locale');

// Choose domain
textdomain("traductions");

// Translation is looking for in ./locale/xx_XX/LC_MESSAGES/traductions.mo now
/*GET Pref language */
function GetPrefLanguage($str_http_languages)
{
    $lang = substr($str_http_languages, 0, 2);

    switch($lang) {
        case 'fr':
            return 'fr_FR';
        break;
        case 'de':
            return 'de_DE';
        break;
        case 'en':
            return 'en_US';
        break;
        default:
            return 'en_US';
    }
}
```